# Do all scalar products in $\mathbb{R}^2$ have the same form?

Tags: linear-algebra

As the title says, I was wondering if all scalar products have the form $\displaystyle \left<x,y\right> = \sum_{i,j \leqslant 2} a_{ij}x_{i}y_{j}$, In that case, one could use a symmetrical matrix to represent it.
My attempt is based on using the properties of the scalar product and reaching the conclusion that the only type of forms that have these properties are bilinear forms. Is this right, or I am missing something?

Comment: $ \langle \sum x_ie_i, \sum y_ie_i \rangle=\sum_{i,j} a_{ij}x_iy_j$ where $a_{ij}= \langle \sum xe_i, \sum e_j\rangle$

Comment: Did you mean $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: Tangential caution: "...one could use a symmetrical matrix to represent it" is correct once we fix a basis of the plane. Do note carefully, however, that under change of basis with matrix $P$, this symmetric matrix transforms by $A \mapsto P^tAP$, not $P^{-1}AP$, i.e., like a quadratic form, _not_ like a linear transformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes (and it generalizes in dimension $n$). Let $\left<,\right>$ is a scalar product on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $a_{11} = \left<(1,0),(1,0)\right>$, $a_{12} = \left<(1,0),(0,1)\right>$, $a_{21} = \left<(0,1),(1,0)\right>$, $a_{22} = \left<(0,1),(0,1)\right>$ and $A$ the $2 \times 2$ matrix made from the $a_{ij}$. The bilinearity condition tells you that for all $x,y$,
$$
\left<x,y\right> = a_{11}x_1y_1 + a_{12}x_1y_2 + a_{21}x_2y_1 + a_{22}x_2y_2 =\ ^txAy.
$$
The symmetry tells you that $a_{12} = a_{21}$ i.e. $A$ is symmetric and the definite positive condition tells you that for all $x \neq 0$, $^txAx > 0$. In this case, we say that $A$ is a positive definite matrix. It is caracterized by the fact that all the eigenvalues of $A$ are positive (in particular, $A$ is invertible).

In the two dimensional case, it is equivalent to $a_{11} > 0$ and $a_{12}^2 < a_{11}a_{22}$. In particular, it obviously implies $a_{22} > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Every bilinear map $\phi\colon\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R$ has the form $\phi(u, v) = u^tMv$ for some $n \times m$ matrix $M$.  This is because setting $u = \sum_iu_ie_i$ and $v = \sum_jv_je_j$ bilinearity gives $\phi(u, v) = \sum_{ij}u_i\phi(e_i, e_j)v_j$, which is the same as $u^tMv$ when we set $M_{ij} = \phi(e_i, e_j)$.

So yes, every scalar product is of the form $u^tMv$ for some square matrix $M$.  If your product is symmetric then $u^tMv = v^tMu$ for all $u, v$.  Applying this to $u = e_i$ and $v = e_j$ gives $M_{ij} = M_{ji}$, so $M = M^t$ is symmetric.